# spring auto populate user details for every request

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC based web application. Currently in my web page i am showing the user first name and last name after user logs in. The way i am doing this is, for every HttpServletRequest that comes into @Controller@RequestMapping, i get the Principal object and get the user details from it, then populate the ModelMap with firstname and lastname attribute. For example here is the sample code

```
@Autowired
private SecurityDetails securityDetails;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showWelcomePage(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model, Principal principal)
{
    securityDetails.populateUserName(model, principal);
            ... lot of code here;
    return "home";
}



public boolean populateUserName(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
    if (principal != null) {
        Object ob = ((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal();
        if(ob instanceof MyUserDetails)
        {
            MyUserDetails ud = (MyUserDetails)ob;
            model.addAttribute("username", ud.getFirstName() + " " + ud.getLastName());
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        logger.debug("principal is null");
        return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is i am having to call the populateUserName method for every RequestMapping. Is there a elegant way, like populating this in Interceptor method, which will result in this method being called just in one place for entire application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its good that you want to prevent duplication of code. Here is how you can do it.

1. Create a custom `HandlerInterceptor` http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html
2. Post handle is the only method of interest for us, for the others return defaults.
3. In the post handle method, you have access to the model and view returned from your controller, go ahead and add whatever you want.
4. The `Principal` will not be available directly here, you will have to look it up using some code like `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`
5. Wire the handler interceptor to intercept all or some of your controllers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Servlet Filters` or `Spring Interceptors`.

BTW, where do you populate the Principal from?

In any case, thats where you should do this populating stuff.

Comment: Principal is autopopulated when it gets to the
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET).

Other thing is how do it get the ModelMap object to populate the attributes inside Servlet Filters or Spring Interceptors?